# obfuscate emails with ruby to protect against harvesters

Tags: ruby, email

Is there a simple gem I could install to show email-addresses in HTML-views only in an obfuscated way?

It would be perfect, if the email-addresses were converted into images.

If that is not possible, a simple replace of the @ with "-at-"?

Or how could I use the solution from this thread:

> [How to protect my e-mail address from spambots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941554/how-to-protect-my-e-mail-address-from-spambots)

Comment: Do you mean emails (contents) or email addresses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whats wrong in using `sub` or `gsub` to achieve the same

```
"example@example.com".sub("@","-at-") #=> example-at-example.com
"example@example.org".sub("@","{at}") #=> example{at}example.org
```

Comment: see my question: this would be the minimum protection, but better would be a gem that does some more obfuscation